# Query a collection by an array of document ids with python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-python

I have list of ids I want to query from a collection.
If I use:

```
query = firebase_client.collection('my_collection').where(
    field_path=field_path.FieldPath.document_id(), op_string='in', value=list_of_ids
).stream()
```

Works, but gives me the warning:

> UserWarning: Detected filter using positional arguments. Prefer using
> the 'filter' keyword argument instead.   return
> query.where(field_path, op_string, value)

I know that if I wanted to query by document field I should use:

```
query = firebase_client.collection('my_collection').where(
     filter=FieldFilter('field', '==', value)
).stream()
```

What is the proper way to query a collection by a list of document ids in order to avoid the warning?

When using:

```
filter=FieldFilter(field_path.FieldPath.document_id(), op_string='in', value=list_of_ids)
```

The script crashes when trying to read the snapshot in a for loop.

> grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of
> RPC that terminated with:
> status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
> details = "**key** filter value must be a Key"
> debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.64.138:443
> {created_time:"2023-11-20T21:50:49.381633-06:00", grpc_status:3,
> grpc_message:"**key** filter value must be a Key"}"

with at the end of the crash message

> google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 **key** filter value
> must be a Key

Comment: Any reason why you can't use FieldFilter as you show now, replacing the three parameters with the three you specified in the first query?

Comment: @DougStevenson when I do so, I get an error when trying to access the snapshot in a for loop.
Updated the question with the corresponding stacktrace for the crash.